# How to sync two databases in different locations without using Replication?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have taken on a project that was written by another developer. The client has asked for a disaster recovery solution, where databases are synced between the two hosting providers. I thought, great, I can just set up Replication, however, half way through the project I realized that the Master site is on a shared host, I therefore, don't have access to my.cnf or any off the core files to that matter.

Ok, so that solution is currently out of the question, so I thought I would duplicate the SQL queries in the PHP (I know that this really is not good practice, but it's a necessity), the code is very poorly written, there are some custom functions, around 200 files and not all of these use these functions for the database calls etc. So duplicating the queries would be a very, very time consuming task.

Does anyone know of another way in which to keep two databases on different servers in sync at all times?

Comment: Hey,

Could you not get in touch with the hosting provider to enable the replication functionality? Also, make sure it isn't already enabled by checking in phpMyAdmin

You may find it is actually enabled already.

Comment: Perhaps migrate to a VPS, AWS instance, etc. first so you can set up replication without doing something crazy. If the client wants DR, they should get off of a shared host first. Crawl, walk, run...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd second the recommendation to move to a VPS. But I recommend Digital Ocean or Linode over Amazon AWS. They are much more affordable and easier to setup. In fact, if the current site is on an "economy" shared host, your client will probably like Digital Ocean's pricing (no, I do not work for them.).

Once the site is on a VPS in, say, New York, you will have the freedom to set up a replicated system in another zone (San Francisco, London, etc.). That will give the client piece of mind worth the hassle of the initial move.

You could pull this off starting at $10/month for two Digital Ocean VPSs--assuming that the client's needs fit within the $5 server's resources.

Comment: Thank you, I do actually use Digital Ocean for all my other sites so I may suggest that we move the site over. The client is however, concerned that by having both the backup and master sites hosted by the same company that if Digital Ocean went down then so would both the sites. Any wise words of wisdom that I can pass on to reassure him that this wouldn't be the case?

Comment: If one Digital Ocean site (or zone) goes down, it's highly unlikely that another zone will also go down. But, if you need to support a high level of paranoia, put one server on Digital Ocean and another on Linode.